# Directory Tree Structure in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an online tool like Eclipse.
On the left hand bar,i have a project explorer like you find in Eclipse IDE.
I want to show a directory structure on that explorer bar.
I am able to receive directory structure as arrays from my Java code.
As i am not good in CSS, i am not able to make a basic layout of directory tree in HTML.
If someone can give me any idea about css to create that directory structure,i will populate the tree structure with my array elements using javascript.

Comment: this could be something to work off: http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/ - google is your friend

Comment: Thank You so much .I will look into it and try to create the tree structure .

Comment: Actually the example which you have referred creates a tree that is neither collapsible or expandable,nut my requirement is to create a project explorer where if a user clicks on some project ,it should show all the files under it .

Comment: Perhaps it would be a coding exercise to implement that part yourself? :) As I said, it was only something to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no longer useful for user2110167, but hopefully for other people:

I have happily used Dynatree in different projects, it allows collapse/expand and in general is very elaborate and flexible. It is open source and MIT licensed.

You can get it from the [project page](https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) or explore its capabilities on the [example page](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html).